# Llamar función despues de otra

Tags: php

Hola una pregunta alguien me podría decir como puedo hacer esto

> $new->select('usuarios')->where('id')

No se si la pregunta este bien formulada así que les dejo mi código

```
class Database extends PDOAbstract{
    public $db = null;
    function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->protected = new PDO('pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=proyecto','postgres','');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            var_dump($e);
        }
    }

    function select($table=null){
        return (is_null($table)) ? "Tabla no puede ser nula" : $this->protected->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table) ;
    }
    function where($sql = null,$where=null){
        var_dump($sql);
        #$sql->queryString.$where;
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase se supone por lo que he investigado tengo que hacer una clase abstracta

```
abstract class PDOAbstract{
 protected $db;
 protected $st;
 abstract function select($value='');
 abstract function where($where);
}
```

pero me arroja este resultado:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::where()

Entiendo que quiere tomarlo de aqui:

```
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
    string(22) "SELECT * FROM usuarios"
}
```

Y que ahí no hay no esta la función, que la función esta en la clase de cree pero no se como hacerlo, soy novato en esto.

Comment: Aclara bien tus dudas por favor, te podemos ayudar pero no adivinar. No pude ver el código que me dejaste... me paso en otro momento en cuando tengas editado tu pregunta... saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error:

En tu función `select` en la clase `Database` estas retornando una instancia de la clase `PDOStatement` para que tu idea funcione debes usar *"fluent functions"* o "funciones fluidas" y necesitas estudiar mas sobre la **POO**(Programación Orientada a Objetos).

Una posible ayuda:

```
class Database 
{
    protected $db = null;
    protected $table = null;
    protected $wheres = [];

    public function __constructor()
    {
        if(is_null($this->db))
        {
            $this->db = new PDO('....');
        }
    }

    public function select($table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
        return $this;
    }

    public function where($value)
    {
        $this->wheres[] = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        if(is_null($this->table))
        {
            throw new Exception('Es necesario definir el nombre de la tabla ');
        }

        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s", $this->table);

        if(count($this->wheres))
        {
            $query .= " WHERE ";
            $query .= implode(" AND ", $this->wheres);
        }

        return $this->db->query($query);
    }
}
```

Entonces esta clase funciona de la siguiente forma:

```
//Esto retorna:
//Database { protected $db => PDO::class, protected $table => null, protected $wheres => [] }
$builder = new Database();

//Esto retorna:
//Database { protected $db => PDO::class, protected $table => 'users', protected $wheres => [] }
$builder->select('users');

//Esto retorna:
//Database { protected $db => PDO::class, protected $table => 'users', protected $wheres => ['email => "user@mail.com"'] }
$builder->where('email => "user@email.com"');

//Esto retorna:
//PDOStatement
$resultado = $bilder->get();
$fetch = $resultado->fetchAll();
```

No se si me hice entender, pero al final usando las *fluent functions*:

```
$result = $builder->select('users')
                  ->where('email => "user@demo.com"')
                  ->where("active = 1")
                  ->get();

$fetch = $result->fetch();
```

Comment: Gracias muchas gracias, resolviste mas de las dudas que tenia muchas gracias. Y creo si tengo que estudiar POO, entiendo las definiciones pero no soy muy culto en programación apenas inicie. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @blaicer de nada, no te olvides de marcar mi respuesta como la correcta :D

Comment: Por cierto en el where también falta el return $this, porque sino marca null y no deja utilizar las demas funciones

Comment: Gracias! ya lo corregí

Comment: quizas esto te pueda ayudar: $this->query .= implode(" AND ", str_replace('"',"'",$this->wheres)); ya que cuando le pones las comillas dobles te manda error en el SQL o mas bien no te ejecuta la sentencia. Y de nada estamos para ayudarnos :)